# Get the list of all media from wordpress.com site

Tags: wordpress

I want to get the list of all media in my wordpress site via REST API. Based on what I found in [Wordpress REST API doc](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/media/#definition) I am using the following GET url but its not working. `https://xxx.wordpress.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media`

Instead of a JSON response, i am getting an HTML page that says `Oops! That page can’t be found.`

Comment: What URL are you actually using? If you're using the `xxx.wordpress.com`, you need to replace that with YOUR URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your site is on wordpress.com (notably different from wordpress.org's self hosted version), you're using the wrong API documentation. You actually want to use [the WordPress.com API Docs](https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/).

Specifically for getting all media items, you'll use the following:

```
https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/$site/media/
where $site is "your-site.wordpress.com"
```

[Related docs](https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/1.1/get/sites/%24site/media/)

Comment: Even the wordpress support didn't give such a clear answer. +100

Answer (score -1):

Using the following code you can get all the attachments. However , you would need access to WordPress theme to run the PHP script.

```html
$query_images_args = array(
  'post_type'      => 'attachment',
  'post_mime_type' => 'image',
  'post_status'    => 'inherit',
  'posts_per_page' => - 1,
);

$query_images = new WP_Query( $query_images_args );

$images = array();
foreach ( $query_images->posts as $image ) {

    $title = get_the_title( $image->ID );
    $images[] = wp_get_attachment_url( $image->ID );

    $caption = wp_get_attachment_caption( $image->ID );

    $attachment = get_post( $image->ID );
    $description = $attachment->post_content;

}
```

If you are not able to run the PHP script inside WordPress , then you have to:

1 - Get the attachment ID through /wp-json/wp/v2/media/

2 - Get the attachment info through /wp-json/wp/v2/media/attachment_ID

This the documentation: https://v2.wp-api.org/reference/media/

Regards.